# Bind Shape properties and attached properties to properties

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a property:

```
public double S { get; set; }
```

...and XAML:

```
<Canvas Name="MainCanvas">
    <Ellipse Canvas.Left="10" Canvas.Top="10" Height="10" Name="ellipse1" Stroke="Black" Width="10"/>
</Canvas>
```

How can I bind both Ellipse `Width` and `Height` properties and attached `Canvas.Left` and `Top` properties so that I can set values to be different fractions of S?

So Canvas.Left and Top could be 1/2f * S while width and height could be 3/4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a value converter in your binding to do the calculation for you.

```
<Ellipse Canvas.Left="{Binding Path=S,Converter=LeftConverter}" ... />
```

In the value converter, you would have:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object paramenter, CultureInfo culture)
{
   double value = Double.Parse(value);
   return value * 0.5;
}
```

This code is untested but should get you started.
Check out this sample [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/bencon/archive/2006/05/10/594886.aspx)